# Android 3.0 statusbar & targetSdkVersion in manifest, menu button

Tags: java, android, android-3.0-honeycomb

I needed to dim Honeycomb's status bar on some screens of my app, so I used the View.setSystemUiVisibility(int) method. But in order for it to work I've changed the targetSdkVersion attribute to 11 in my manifest. Now everything works perfectly, but the "menu" button in the status bar has disappeared so I can't access some options. How do I show it while keeping targetSdkVersion=11?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I show it while keeping targetSdkVersion=11?

You don't. Your menu will appear in your action bar. If you removed the action bar, put it back, or do not use an options menu.

Comment: No, it's not an option. I don't want to completely redesign my app, I just want to use a couple of features introduced in Honeycomb.

Comment: @Grishka: Your ***ONLY*** choices are to put the action bar back, do not use an options menu, or use a `targetSdkVersion` of less than `11`. And that latter choice will make you look like a lousy programmer as the months go by and an increasing percentage of apps upgrade to the `11` look-and-feel. Relatively few apps need to drop the action bar (many games, some video players), so I humbly suggest that you strongly consider restoring the action bar, in which case your options menu will appear in it.

Comment: So I've decided to add a menu button to my custom ActionBar-like title bar.