# android menu button availability

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

In the past I've kept my game's options behind the physical menu button for these reasons:

- I don't have to have on-screen buttons in-game.
- The menu action is consistent with the android user experience; it's not something unique to my app.

In some situations Android provides a soft menu button in the bottom system bar.  Looking forward, though (e.g. with recent devices and targetSdkVersions), it seems there's no guaranteed way to have a menu button without implementing the new ActionBar.

If my understanding is correct, I see these options:

1. Use the ActionBar.  Say goodbye to a big chunk of screen real-estate, especially in landscape orientation.
2. Implement my own on-screen menu button.  I've seen this in other games, and it strikes me as inconsistent and terrible.
3. Target an old sdk version.  I don't like this.

Is my understanding correct?  Anyone have additional suggestions for my list?

relevant links:

http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/compatibility.html

[Android Menu Button on 4.0 Devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8264076/android-menu-button-on-4-0-devices)

[Android 3.0 statusbar & targetSdkVersion in manifest, menu button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8646980/android-3-0-statusbar-targetsdkversion-in-manifest-menu-button)

[android honeycomb menu button target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5279148/android-honeycomb-menu-button-target)

Comment: The day after I posted this question they made it clear that menu buttons are going away: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Is my understanding correct?

Yes.

> Anyone have additional suggestions for my list?

Your definition of "terrible" differs from mine. IMHO, any game that has its own stylized graphics and look (i.e., just about anything using the `Canvas` or OpenGL) should have implemented its own "menu" from the outset, and therefore largely would be oblivious to these changes.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a tiny , transparent menu button of your own. Many games do that. That way you are not dependent on anyone and you don't loose any screen space.

Edit : Your menu button could then have follow your game's design.